# kubectl cannot connect to AKS cluster frequently

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have a simple test cluster of 1 node on AKS. I copied the `.kube/config` file from the cloud shell session to local machine. Now when I try to run `kubectl` I mostly get these two error:

1. `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [xx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx]:443: connect: network is unreachable`
2. `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup xxxxxxxxx-dns-3bwmvrwa.hcp.centralindia.azmk8s.io on 192.168.1.1:53: lame referral`

Ocassionaly the `kubectl` command run fine it returns the expected output, but 90 percent of the time it throws these two errors. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have some kind of proxy, custom dns or something like that in your local network?

In future I would avoid copying the kubeconfig by just using the azure cli on your local machine. Then use the command:

```
az aks get-credentials -n <name of aks> -g <resource group>
```

This will automatically copy the right parts into your local kubeconfig.